# Overloading >> and << with an array of objects in the definition

Tags: c++

I'm trying to overload the `<<` and `>>` operators.  I have created my friend functions in my header file.  Then, I copy and pasted pretty much my entire main function into the `>>` overload definition in the source file.  The trouble I'm having is that the array of objects is spitting out errors when these functions are called with this array.

Example:

```
grid[i].findPerimeter();
grid[i].findArea();
grid[i].findWidth();
grid[i].findHeight();
grid[i].printGrid();
```

Calling these functions in the definition of the overloaded operator tells me that "`no operator "[]" matches these operands`".

This is the beginning of the definition for the overloaded operator.

```
istream &operator>> (istream &input, Rectangle &grid)
{
ifstream inFile;

Rectangle grid[10];

int x11, x21, y11, y21, choice, numRectangles = 0, i;
char inner1, outer1;
string name1;

inFile.open ("rectangle.in");
outFile.open ("rectangle.out");
```

For a little background, I should tell you that this program accepts input from a file and stores data about rectangles, ie coordinates.  I'm trying to overload these operators as part of an assignment.

Comment: operator `[]` is failing, you should overload that operator for Rectangle.

Comment: You have `grid` as a function argument as well as a local variable. That's a problem.

Comment: @faranwath according to the parameters of `operator>>` grid is a `Rectangle` not an array

Answer (score 1):

You're program is failing because `grid` is a parameter and a variable. You should consider changing the name of one of these.

Comment: This fixed every error that was being thrown out by using the grid parameter to call those functions.  Thanks!  Also, now the last "}" that closes the overload definition for the >> operator is spitting out an error saying "expected a declaration".